# Why Cassandra doesn't let to query clustering key by IN restriction?

Tags: select, cassandra, cql, nosql

Does anyone know why I cannot use query where I restrict clustering column by `IN` and I `select` collection column?

Let me elaborate on that. Let's say I have data model similar to the following:

```
create table inventory (
                sku text,
                class text,
                unit text,
                node text,
                supply map<text, frozen<delta_and_time>>,
                supply_compacted int,
                primary key ((sku, class, unit), node));
```

when I try to use following select statement:

```
select sku, class, unit, node, supply_compacted where sku = '0' 
           and class = 'good' and unit = 'each' and node in ('1', '2', '3')
```

everything is fine. But when I try to `select *` with the same restrictions I get follow
ing error:

```
Cannot restrict clustering columns by IN relations when a collection is selected by the query
```

I tried to find out why there is such restriction in C* but I couldn't find anything. Also I looked into the code but there is no information why such check is performed.

Does anyone know what is the reason of such restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation based on how Collection Data types were "hacked" into the existing storage engine. A Map collection is implemented by storing each key as a unique column name in the same area as the clustering column. Thus making it difficult for Cassandra to efficiently do an "IN" operation especially for large collection sizes for each "row".

However I do feel that you could re-work your data model to get around this limitation and not even use a Collection type (since they have many issues associated with them if your are not careful). It looks like "supply_compacted" could be a roll up of the total inventory within the supply map? If so you could do the following:

```
create table inventory (
  sku text,
  class text,
  unit text,
  node text,
  supply_compacted int static, -- stored once, total amount of inventory across all nodes
  supply frozen<delta_and_time>,
  primary key ((sku, class, unit), node)
);
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on the `same area as the clustering column`?

Comment: That is the most bizarre limitation I have seen so far in a technology...

Answer (score 0):

My original thought is that the constraint is due to the impact on the memory and the network to get collections, since multiple collections can be returned at once with the in restriction. However, I found that the query is working if it's less restricted by only specifying the partition key.

My test data (on Cassandra 3.7):

```
cqlsh:test> create table mytable(X text, Y text, Z text, mylist list<int>, primary key (X,Y));
cqlsh:test> insert into mytable (X,Y,Z,mylist) values('x','y1','z1',[1,2,3]);
cqlsh:test> insert into mytable (X,Y,Z,mylist) values('x','y2','z2',[4,5,6]);
cqlsh:test> select x,y,z from mytable where x = 'x' and y in ('y1');

 x | y  | z
---+----+----
 x | y1 | z1

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test> select * from mytable where x = 'x' and y in ('y1');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot restrict clustering columns by IN relations when a collection is selected by the query"
cqlsh:test> select * from mytable where x = 'x';

 x | y  | mylist    | z
---+----+-----------+----
 x | y1 | [1, 2, 3] | z1
 x | y2 | [4, 5, 6] | z2

(2 rows)
```

The underlying sstable dump:

```
$ sstabledump mb-1-big-Data.db
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "x" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 15,
        "clustering" : [ "y1" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2016-09-13T08:14:33.172799Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "z", "value" : "z1" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2016-09-13T08:14:33.172798Z", "local_delete_time" : "2016-09-13T08:14:33Z" } },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "1a1a0760-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "1" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "1a1a0761-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "2" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "1a1a0762-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 99,
        "clustering" : [ "y2" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2016-09-13T08:14:49.772718Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "z", "value" : "z2" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2016-09-13T08:14:49.772717Z", "local_delete_time" : "2016-09-13T08:14:49Z" } },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "23fefce0-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "4" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "23fefce1-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "5" },
          { "name" : "mylist", "path" : [ "23fefce2-798a-11e6-851a-e3954ecad15b" ], "value" : "6" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see the collection is not really different from the non primary key column, except for the aggregation that's needed before returning it to the client. I wonder if this was a constraint on the old thrift implementation and got carried over even though there is no obvious reason why this can't be done.